# WebdriverIO wait functions not reading custom timeout values, In short none of the wait functions wait more than 3000ms

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriver-io

I am trying to automate an Android application using appium and webdriverIO inside a typescript framework. I am using async mode.

My issue is when I am trying to use a waitUntil or any of the wait functions, they don't wait more than 3000ms, regardless of whatever custom timeout value I pass to the function. My best guess is, this is may be because of dependency issues.

Let me know if you guys need any additional information. I am attaching snippets of package.json and tsconfig to give you guys a brief overview of the packages I am using

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^14.14.28",
"@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
"@wdio/cli": "^7.2.3",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"husky": "^5.1.3",
"nodemon": "^2.0.7",
"ts-node": "^9.1.1",
"ts-node-dev": "^1.1.1",
"tslint": "^6.1.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.5"


},
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.1.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.1.2",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.1.1",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.1.1",
    "appium-chromedriver": "^4.27.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chromedriver": "^89.0.0",
    "tslog": "^3.1.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0",
    "webdriverio": "^5.10.4"
  }
```

tscnofig.json

```
"types": [
  "node", "webdriverio/async", "@wdio/mocha-framework"
],
```

My wait until Function is as follows :

```
    async waitUntil(params: any) {

       const waitOnElement = await this.client.$(element);
    
       await waitOnElement.waitUntil( async () => {
          return await waitOnElement.getText() === text
       }, {
        "timeout": timeout
       })

    }
```